# How can i compare two different columns from different document libraries?

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I got two list called List A , List B. List A has got columns called "Number" And "Title".. List B will reach the "Number" and compare , if it is the same number will show List A 's "Title".

### List A   Number   Title

```
     1        sharepoint
     2        stackoverflow
```

### List B   Number    Name    Title

```
     1         aaa     sharepoint
     1         bbb     sharepoint
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are creating a lookup column in **List B**, please select the other field also in the list as shown in figure, I have selected **City** is a lookup column and corresponding **state** and **pincode** columns also selected so that you can get the values directly from **List B**

[image]